# JQuery: Opacity animation with sticky navbar only works once

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate, sticky

I have a sticky navbar using this code:

```
var stickyNavTop = $("#mynavbar").offset().top;
var winheight = $(window).height();
var relation = stickyNavTop / winheight;

function fixNavBar() {

    var stickyNav = function(){
        var winheight = $(window).height();
        var elempos = winheight * relation;
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scrollTop > elempos) { 
            $("#mynavbar").addClass('sticky');
            $("#logo").animate({opacity: 1}) // <- first animation
        } else {
            $("#mynavbar").removeClass('sticky');
            $("#logo").animate({opacity: 0}) // <- second animation
        }

    };

    stickyNav();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        stickyNav();
    })
}

fixNavBar();
```

The css:

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}

#logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

When I only add the first animation it works fine. When I add the second one to reset the opacity to 0 when scrolling up it executes immediatly when the page is loaded. In this case, the logo is always invisible.

I uploaded a [preview here](http://netzkratzen.de/bootstrap/) (minimize window, untill menu-icon appears; second animation commented out)

Many thanks in advance...
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to show the small logo when the top scroll position is after the first brown block and to hide it otherwise.

Each time you scroll, you are triggering a new animation, jQuery is queuing all animations.
To hide the logo when scrolling up, you have to stop all previous unfinished animations.

```
    if (scrollTop > elempos) { 
        $("#mynavbar").addClass('sticky');
        $("#logo").animate({opacity: 1})
    } else {
        $("#mynavbar").removeClass('sticky');
        $("#logo").stop(true); // Stop all previous animations
        $("#logo").animate({opacity: 0})
    }
```

Comment: Works nice! Thanks a lot!